# Can I Get the Source Range Of Excel Clipboard Data?

Tags: vba, clipboard, excel-2003, clipboarddata

If the Clipboard contains an Excel Worksheet Range, you can access that Range's Data with the DataObject Object

Can you also find the actual **Source Range** (ie Worksheet, Row & Column) of that Data?

Alternatively, can you find the **Last Copied** Range, which is indicated with a Dashed Outline Border (**NOT** the Selected Range)?

Preferably using Excel 2003 VBA

Answer (score 4):

This code is being used in Excel 2019 64 bit to get the range of the cells on the clipboard as opposed to the contents of the cells.

fGetClipRange returns a range object for the Excel range that is cut or copied onto the clipboard, including book and sheet. It reads it directly from the clipboard using the "Link" format, and requires the ID number for this format. The ID associated with the registered formats can change, so fGetFormatId finds the current format ID from a format name. Use Application.CutCopyMode to determine whether the cells were cut or copied.

This site was useful for working with the clipboard in VBA: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal lngFormat As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumClipboardFormats Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardFormatNameA Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

'2020-02-11 get excel copy or cut range from clipboard
Function fGetClipRange() As Range
Dim strGetClipRange As String    'return range
Dim lptClipData As LongPtr  'pointer to clipboard data
Dim strClipData As String   'clipboard data
Dim intOffset As Integer    'for parsing clipboard data
Dim lngRangeLink As Long  'clipboard format
Const intMaxSize As Integer = 256   'limit for r1c1 to a1 conversion
    lngRangeLink = fGetFormatId("Link") 'we need the id number for link format
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then GoTo conDone  'could not open clipboard
    lptClipData = GetClipboardData(lngRangeLink)    'pointer to clipboard data
    If IsNull(lptClipData) Then GoTo conDone    'could not allocate memory
    lptClipData = GlobalLock(lptClipData)   'lock clipboard memory so we can reference
    If IsNull(lptClipData) Then GoTo conDone    'could not lock clipboard memory
    intOffset = 0   'start parsing data
    strClipData = Space$(intMaxSize)    'initialize string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, lptClipData + intOffset)  'copy pointer to string
    If strClipData = Space$(intMaxSize) Then GoTo conDone   'not excel range on clipboard
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1)    'trim null character
    If strClipData <> "Excel" Then GoTo conDone     'not excel range on clipboard
    intOffset = intOffset + 1 + Len(strClipData)    'can't retrieve string past null character
    strClipData = Space$(intMaxSize)    'reset string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, lptClipData + intOffset)  'book and sheet next
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1)
    strGetClipRange = "'" & strClipData & "'!"  'get book and sheet
    intOffset = intOffset + 1 + Len(strClipData)    'next offset
    strClipData = Space$(intMaxSize)    'initialize string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, lptClipData + intOffset)  'range next
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1)
    strGetClipRange = strGetClipRange & strClipData 'add range
    strGetClipRange = Application.ConvertFormula(strGetClipRange, xlR1C1, xlA1)
    Set fGetClipRange = Range(strGetClipRange)  'range needs a1 style
conDone:
    Call GlobalUnlock(lptClipData)
    Call CloseClipboard
End Function

'2020-02-11 clipboard format id number changes so get it from format name
Function fGetFormatId(strFormatName As String) As Long
Dim lngFormatId As Long
Dim strFormatRet As String
Dim intLength As Integer
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then Exit Function   'could not open clipboard
    intLength = Len(strFormatName) + 3  'we only need a couple extra to make sure there isn't more
    lngFormatId = 0 'start at zero
    Do
        strFormatRet = Space(intLength) 'initialize string
        GetClipboardFormatNameA lngFormatId, strFormatRet, intLength    'get the name for the id
        strFormatRet = Trim(strFormatRet)   'trim spaces
        If strFormatRet <> "" Then  'if something is left
            strFormatRet = Left(strFormatRet, Len(strFormatRet) - 1)    'get rid of terminal character
            If strFormatRet = strFormatName Then    'if it matches our name
                fGetFormatId = lngFormatId  'this is the id number
                Exit Do 'done
            End If
        End If
        lngFormatId = EnumClipboardFormats(lngFormatId) 'get the next used id number
    Loop Until lngFormatId = 0  'back at zero after last id number
    Call CloseClipboard 'close clipboard
End Function
```

Comment: another method also based on the "Link" format is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23119068/2981328

Comment: Wow, this is some of the most beautiful code i've seen shared online. Aside from works perfectly on first try, the care you've taken to properly handle each step of the process, each exception, your variable names are understandable and well prefixed, superb commenting, understandable and plain English, i like how you keep the code block contiguous by putting comments on the side, you put a heavy process into its own subproc `fGetFormatId`  instead of making your main proc twice and long and twice as hard to understand.

Comment: This provides a much less obtrusive method than `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, because this method doesn't require running VBA every time the users clicks on the sheet. That's asking for trouble.

Comment: I applaud your fearless use of GoTo :D   I see no risks, but i haven't studied it.

Comment: I understand the need for this much complexity, but i wish there was a simpler implementation. Notice you say `If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0` twice. That's a conditional and an API call. Can you change `If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then GoTo conDone` to `If lngRangeLink = 0 Then GoTo conDone`

Comment: Wow, thanks for your comments, johny why. I've never received such high praise. I generally avoid GoTo, but I've done a lot of programming in assembly and sometimes I use a little of that. You're right that the OpenClipboard is redundant. fGetFormatId  makes the main routine neater, but I also wanted it work stand alone so I could use it for other things.

Comment: I have tried to use this code. As there are many functions, so i am bit confused, how i can use this code to **get copied(marching ants border) range**. Like if i want to see the copied range in **msgBox** or **Debug.Print** how i can get, pls pls kindly help?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, no - the clipboard object seems to only contain the values of the cells (though Excel obviously somehow remembers the border):

```
Sub testClipborard()

    Dim test As String
    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

    clipboard.GetFromClipboard
    test = clipboard.GetText

    MsgBox (test)

End Sub
```

Note you will need a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Library to get this to run (and if you don't have values in the cells it will also fail).

---

That being said, you can try something like the following - add this to a module in the VBA editor.

```
Public NewRange As String 
Public OldRange As String 
Public SaveRange As String 
Public ChangeRange As Boolean
```

And use the following in a sheet object

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 

     'save previous selection
    OldRange = NewRange 

     'get current selection
    NewRange = Selection.Address 

     'check if copy mode has been turned off
    If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then 
        ChangeRange = False 
    End If 

     'if copy mode has been turned on, save Old Range
    If Application.CutCopyMode = 1 And ChangeRange = False Then 
         'boolean to hold "SaveRange" address til next copy/paste operation
        ChangeRange = True 
         'Save last clipboard contents range address
        SaveRange = OldRange 
    End If 

End Sub
```

It seemingly works, but, it's also probably fairly prone to different bugs as it is attempting to get around the issues with the clipboard.  http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=66773

Answer (score 0):

I completely rewrote the previous answer because I needed to get other kinds of data into Excel besides ranges. The new code is more versatile, and gets different formats off the clipboard as strings. Extracting the Excel range ends up being much simpler, and I'm also using it for bitmaps and text.

The last routine gets the number for non-built-in formats. The middle routine gets the clipboard contents as a string for the specified format. The first routine parses the Excel range from this string with the split function.

```
'https://officeaccelerators.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/reading-data-with-format-from-clipboard/
'https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ee9e0d28-0f1e-467f-8d1d-1a86b2db2878/a-clipboard-object-for-vba-including-microsoft-word?forum=worddev

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongLong) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function RegisterClipboardFormat Lib "user32.dll" Alias "RegisterClipboardFormatA" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (lpvDest As Any, lpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
#Else
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function RegisterClipboardFormat Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterClipboardFormatA" (ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (lpDest As Any, lpSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
#End If

'test routine displays a message box with the marching ants range
'_2022_10_30
Function fTest_GetClipboardRange()
Dim rngClipboard As Range
    Set rngClipboard = fGetClipboardRange
    If rngClipboard Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("No Excel range was found on the clipboard.")
    ElseIf Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then 'this is always copy because of sheet add
        MsgBox (fGetClipboardRange.Address & " has been copied to the clipboard.")
    ElseIf Application.CutCopyMode = xlCut Then
        MsgBox (fGetClipboardRange.Address & " has been cut to the clipboard.")
    End If
End Function

'reads excel copy-paste range from the clipboard and returns range object or nothing if not found
'_2022_03_19
Function fGetClipboardRange() As Range  'get excel copy or cut range from clipboard
Dim strClipboard As String  'raw clipboard data
Dim arrClipboard() As String    'parse into an array
    Set fGetClipboardRange = Nothing    'default is nothing
    
    strClipboard = fGetClipboardData("link")    'get the link data string
    If strClipboard = "" Then Exit Function 'done if it's empty
    arrClipboard = Split(strClipboard, Chr(0))  'else parse at null characters
    If arrClipboard(0) <> "Excel" Then Exit Function    'excel should be first
    strClipboard = "'" & arrClipboard(1) & "'!" & arrClipboard(2)   'parse the range from the others
    strClipboard = Application.ConvertFormula(strClipboard, xlR1C1, xlA1)   'convert to a1 style
    Set fGetClipboardRange = Range(strClipboard)    'range needs a1 style

End Function

'read clipboard for specified format into string or null string
'_2022_03_19
Function fGetClipboardData(strFormatId As String) As String 'read clipboard into string
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Dim hMem As LongPtr 'memory handle
    Dim lngPointer As LongPtr   'memory pointer
#Else
    Dim hMem As Long 'memory handle
    Dim lngPointer As Long   'memory pointer
#End If
Dim arrData() As Byte   'clipboard reads into this array
Dim lngSize As Long 'size on clipboard
Dim lngFormatId As Long 'id number, for format name
    fGetClipboardData = ""  'default

    lngFormatId = fGetClipboardFormat(strFormatId)  'get format
    If lngFormatId <= 0 Then Exit Function  'zero if format not found

    CloseClipboard  'in case clipboard is open
    If CBool(OpenClipboard(0)) Then 'open clipboard
        hMem = GetClipboardData(lngFormatId)    'get memory handle
        If hMem > 0 Then    'if there's a handle
            lngSize = CLng(GlobalSize(hMem))    'get memory size
            If lngSize > 0 Then 'if we know the size
                lngPointer = GlobalLock(hMem)   'get memory pointer
                If lngPointer > 0 Then  'make sure we have the pointer
                    ReDim arrData(0 To lngSize - 1) 'size array
                    CopyMemory arrData(0), ByVal lngPointer, lngSize    'data from pointer to array
                    fGetClipboardData = StrConv(arrData, vbUnicode) 'convert array to string
                End If
                GlobalUnlock hMem   'unlock memory
            End If
        End If
    End If
    CloseClipboard  'don't leave the clipboard open
    
End Function

'return format number form format number, format number from format name or 0 for not found
'_2022_03_19
Function fGetClipboardFormat(strFormatId As String) As Long 'verify, or get format number from format name
Dim lngFormatId As Long 'format id number
    fGetClipboardFormat = 0 'default false

    If IsNumeric(strFormatId) Then  'for format number
        lngFormatId = CLng(strFormatId) 'use number for built in format
        CloseClipboard  'in case clipboard is already open
        If CBool(OpenClipboard(0)) = False Then 'done if can't open clipboard
        ElseIf CBool(IsClipboardFormatAvailable(lngFormatId)) = True Then   'true if format number found
            fGetClipboardFormat = lngFormatId   'return format number
        End If
        CloseClipboard  'don't leave the clipboard open
    Else
        lngFormatId = RegisterClipboardFormat(strFormatId & Chr(0)) 'else get number from format name
        If (lngFormatId > &HC000&) Then fGetClipboardFormat = lngFormatId   'if valid return format number
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I have tried to use this code. As there are many functions, so i am bit confused, how i can use this code to **get copied(marching ants border) range**. Like if i want to see the copied range in **msgBox** or **Debug.Print** how i can get, pls pls kindly help?

Comment: MsgBox (fGetClipboardRange.Address)

Comment: Hi @oddClock, Thanks for your reply. Can you please help to publish the code for 32bit and 64bit Excel? As per my knowledge, I have to use `#If VBA7 Then (need to add PtrSafe)... #Else.. .#End If`. I already tried this method, but this is not working. Anything is related to `#win64`, Sorry I am not familiar with code conversion.

Comment: Hey Zohir Emon- I added the switches for 32bit, but I don't have a machine to test it on. Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I have tested. This is working fine in 32bit and 64bit excel. You are great in the Excel world. @oddclock