# CutCopyMode automatically reset

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet, and a button on it (Excel forms button, not ActiveX).
Depending on current selection, the button is moved/resized or made visible/unvisible (handled by Worksheet_SelectionChange event).
All this was designed in Excel 2010 and worked fine until some end users reported errors while using the workbook in Excel 2007. The issue is, that when you copy/cut a range, and then change selection CutCopyMode is reset to False (floating frame around what was copied disappears). This does not happen in Excel 2010. I found out CutCopyMode is reset when I programatically modify button properties (top, height, left, visible, backcolor are modified each cancels CutCopyMode).
Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the logic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12117460/3897316), it seems that you will need to keep track of the range on the clipboard before modifying your button, and then recopying/recutting after modifying your button to restore the original range to the clipboard.

Comment: Although I expected some way for CutCopyMode not to be canceled, the way you suggested seems to be the only one. Thanks