# Copy multiple cells in excel once - paste into another app for each field

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a row of 10 fields in excel.  I can use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> for this.

When I paste the fields - I would like to only paste 1 field at a time into different fields in a different app.

Is it possible to copy the row fields once and when I paste into the other app - I can use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> but only paste the 1st field, so I can move to the 2nd field and paste the 2nd copied field from excel?

Comment: Can you copy multiple cells and only paste the first cell? If not, what makes you think you can do that programmatically?

Comment: You can get a reference to the copied range as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60033558/445425).  Once you have that, you write a routine to paste those cells one at a time.  Assign it to ctrl-V or another key combo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 and Windows 11 have a “Clipboard History” tool that allows the Clipboard to store multiple items that can be pasted at any time. If you copy each item you want to transfer individually, you can use this to approximate your desired functionality.

Microsoft turns this new “Clipboard History” feature off by default.
Follow these steps to turn the “Clipboard History” feature on:

1. Open Settings.
2. Search for "Clipboard".
3. Select "Save Multiple Clipboard Items".
4. Toggle the “Clipboard history” setting to On.

The Clipboard History feature should now be active.
Now, when you copy (or cut) items to the Clipboard all of those items will be stored (until restart) instead of being over-written when you copy or cut something new.

However, you can’t access the stored Clipboard items simply by clicking Paste or pressing Ctrl+V. If you want to paste one of the previously stored items, press the Windows+V key combination. Pressing Windows+V will bring up the entire list of previously stored Clipboard items. Select one from this list to paste it in.