# Excel VBA "Origin" Counterpart of "Target" for Copy and Paste Events

Tags: excel, vba, copy, target, cut

I'm attempting to catch the origin cell of a copy/cut using the Worksheet_Change event.  I couldn't find an "Origin" counterpart to the "Target" variable to catch the source range when copying/cutting.  I was looking for something that would work like:

```
MyOriginAddress = Origin.Address
```

Similar to how one could write:

```
MyTargetAddress = Target.Address
```

Is there a way of capturing this information?

Thanks!

Comment: See previously here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73179268/478884

Comment: Ouch.  Thank you, Tim!